# sqlite before insert trigger to insert or update if name exists

Tags: sqlite, insert-update, on-duplicate-key

i am currently working or SQLite database and I am looking for solution to
minimize the redundant data in my table.
I have a primary key that auto-increment, name as a text and date entered in date('now'). My question is when inserting if name is exist i would rather update the date to new current date. 
I know there is a insert or replace method(which i don't understand) i need this working on trigger as before insert to check every time before inserting.
is there any solution ?

```
CREATE TABLE `address` (
`address_id`    INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
`address_name`  TEXT,
`lat`   BLOB NOT NULL,
`lng`   BLOB NOT NULL,
`date`  NUMERIC
```

);

Comment: If you're using sqlite 3.24 or better, you can make the name column unique, and use [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) syntax to insert or update rows.

Comment: Also, you probably don't want to be using AUTOINCREMENT: https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: what do you mean by upsert syntax? could you give me any examples?@Shawn

Comment: There are a few examples in the documentation i linked too.